# Adding a new key to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

**JSON:**

```
{'result':[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]}
```

**I am trying to add another dictionary this list, like this:**

```
dict = {'result':[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]}
length = len(dict['result'])
print(length)

dict['results'][length+1] = [new_result]
```

**I keep getting:**

```
dict['result'][length+1] = [new_result]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: The problem before: You had a list with 2 elements. so you can acces `[0]` and `[1]`. You are trying to index `[lenght+1] = [3]`. This index is not in the range 0-1. (`[2]` would also be outside the range of the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using the list, you can append a new item to the list

```
data_dict['results'].append(new_result)
```

As Moses Koledoye  wrote at the comment you can do also:

```
data_dict['results'].extend([new_result])
```

Comment: `.append(new_result)` or `.extend([new_result])`

Comment: WOW! This works! Whoooo! This works! Don't know why it didn't work earlier though.

Comment: @haxxir411: Because your code was totally different and wasn't doing what you thought it will do ;)